# The real part of the sum $(i-1)+(i-1)^2+(i-1)^3....+(i-1)^{2013}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm not sure how to go around this one. Factorizing doesn't seem to work and there isn't a clear pattern to work by that I see.

EDIT:
So apparently I need to add context and stuff. I removed the checkmark from the answer because the answer for this question is one of these options (according to my book)
A:$2^{1007}$
B:$-2^{1007}$
C:$-2^{1007}-1$
D:$1$
E:$-1$

Using the formula mentioned in the answers comments:
$$S=(x-x^{n+1})/(1-x)$$

I get

$$(i-1-(i-1)^{2014})/(2-i)$$

Writing $(i-1)^{2014}$ in its polar form and calculating it gives me $(i-1)^{2014}=i2^{1007}$

Further simplifying this, I get the real part as something like $(2^{1007}-3)/5$

Which is not one of the options I have.

Comment: Looks like a geometric series!

Comment: "Factorizing doesn't seem to work" Please explain what "Factorizing" refers to in this context.

Comment: Welp, not really sure what to do with that?

Comment: $a + a^2 + \cdots + a^n = ...$

Comment: Basically, I tried taking out (i-1) from the successive powers of (i-1), but that  didn't simplify anything (that I could see)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a geometric series with first term $a=i-1$ and common ratio $r=i-1$. As such, the sum to the 2013th term is:

$$S_{2013}={a(1-r^{2013})\over 1-r}={(i-1)\left(1-(i-1)^{2013}\right)\over 1-(i-1)}={(i-1)\left(1-(i-1)^{2013}\right)\over 2-i}$$
The trickiest part is probably the 2013th power, but we can simplify it using the polar form:

$$(i-1)^{2013}=(\sqrt 2 e^{-i\pi/4})^{2013}=2^{2013/2}e^{-2013i\pi/4}=2^{2012/2}2^{1/2}e^{-2012i\pi/4}e^{-i\pi/4}=2^{1006}2^{1/2}e^{-503i\pi}e^{-i\pi/4}=-2^{1006}\sqrt 2 e^{-i\pi/4}=-2^{1006}(i-1)=2^{1006}(1-i)$$

I'll leave the rest as an exercise!

Comment: Hmm, is there any way to calculate $(i-1)^{2013}$ without using the polar form of complex numbers (or at least $e$)? I really don't get the downvotes, I genuinely didn't know this formula for geometric series.

I found the exercise in a book meant for students who haven't learned these concepts yet.

Either way, thanks a lot!

Comment: you *could* use the binomial expansion formula for $(a+b)^n$, but it would take you a while to get back to the final result

Comment: for the geometric series sum formula, call the sum $S=x+x^2+x^3+...+x^n$. Then $xS=x^2+x^3+x^4+...+x^{n+1}$. Subtract one from the other and factorise to get $S(1-x)=x-x^{n+1}=x(1-x^n)$ so that $S={x(1-x^n)\over 1-x}$

Comment: @Essam, I can't really understand what you have written but it looks like you are using the *infinite* series formula, but this question is about a finite series

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28i-1%29%281-%28i-1%29%5E2013%29%2F%282-i%29 which agrees - not sure what the problem is here

Comment: @danimal sorry, you are right (+1)

Comment: So deriving the same thing I got $(i-1)^{2013}=2^{1006}*(1-i)$ and wolframalpha agrees so you made a sign mistake somewhere along the line.

Answer (score 1):

Since $i-1=\sqrt2\,e^{3\pi i/4}$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
(i-1)^{2014}
&=2^{1007}\,e^{\pi i/2}\\
&=2^{1007}i
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{2013}(i-1)^k
&=\frac{(i-1)-(i-1)^{2014}}{1-(i-1)}\\
&=\frac{(i-1)-2^{1007}i}{2-i}\\
&=\frac{-1-(2^{1007}-1)i}{2-i}\\
&=\frac{(-1-(2^{1007}-1)i)(2+i)}5\\
&=\frac{(2^{1007}-3)-(2^{1008}-1)i}5\\
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the value for the real part in the question is correct. (Mathematica agrees.)